# How to remove the 3d effect in the font

Tags: html, css, fonts

I don't know why I am getting this 3d effect in words. How can I remove the effect and flatten the words?

The font family is Poppins

```
   body {font-family: "Poppins";}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you applied any text shadow?

Comment: it's happening because of your color combination

Comment: I think the "3d" effect is an illusion caused by the contrast of the font color and the background.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can do any formatting with CSS.

```
a {font-style: normal;}
```

will make font style as normal

Answer (score 0):

There may be a CSS conflict. Try this. Change class & the colors as suitable.
add

```
text-shadow: none;


.text-class
{
    text-shadow: none;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I think it is not CSS conflicts.  for the background color and text color both combination.

Comment: But, there's a black line. I think it's better if we can view an inspection view of browser